# saltstack state file: how to access a list element in a salt grain via Jinja

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I try to evaluate the value of a grains list in jinja but do not know how. The list entry I am looking for is the minor osversion in

> `grain:osrelease_info`

```
salt-call -g |grep -C2 osrelease_info
    osrelease:
        15.99
    osrelease_info:
        - 15
        - 99
```

In a state-file I would like to evaluate the minior osrelease value in a jinja expression like this one:

```
{% if grains['osmajorrelease'] == '15' and grains['osrelease_info'][1] >= 99 %}
  ... 
{% endif %}
```

However the syntax I tried above to access index:1 of the osrelease_info list does not report an error but doesn't work either.
So how can I access the list entry containing value "99" in Jinja?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer myself alltough it is a little strange. The problem was not the expression

> {% ... and grains['osrelease_info'][1] >= 99 %}

but instead the string comparison before:

> {% if grains['osmajorrelease'] == '15' ... %}

All I changed was to convert the string '15' to an int. So the following expression does what I originally wanted:

```
{% if grains['osmajorrelease'] == 15 and grains['osrelease_info'][1] >= 99 %}
  ... 
{% endif %}
```

This is weird since I use exactly the same comparision (grains['osmajorrelease'] == '15')  in other state files with success.

Comment: The type of the `osmajorrelease` grain changed at some point. It should always be an integer now.